# Firebase says "You do not have permission to create a test matrix with Test Lab." when trying to launch robotest

Tags: android, firebase, testing, firebase-test-lab

When I try to launch a test with Firebase, I receive this message:
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: you have to enable Cloud Tool Results API

Comment: I have enabled this permissions in the console, but still doesn't work

Comment: Is this in a project you created with your own account?  Or are you possibly looking at someone else's project that you have read access to?

Comment: Also have this problem, none of the solutions proposed here works. I'm owner of the project, billing is enabled (blaze plan) and Google Cloud Testing API is enabled for the project...

Answer (score 0):

Before you get started, you need to enable billing for your project. If you don't have an active billing account, add one and then connect your project to that billing account. You will need ownership or edit permissions in your project. Also, if you are using Spark Plan (free plan) then most probably you have exhausted your daily limit for tests.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to enable "Google Cloud Testing API".
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

Comment: Amazingly this worked if I turned it off and then on again!